# Where can I obtain Trek permits for Har-ki-doon?

Tags: india, paperwork, trekking, permits, himalayas

I asked the same question [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9658/trekking-har-ki-doon). But it seems this community have more members and activity.

We are going to Sankri -- Har-ki-doon trek. So, from various sources in internet we found that a forest permit is necessary for the trek.

From where should we obtain this? And is it mandatory to hire a guide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a lot to find about permits, but [you can find where you need to pay for entrance, and photo and video cameras.](http://www.euttaranchal.com/tourism/govind-wildlife-sanctuary.php)
In the extended text you can find the text:

> **Govind Wildlife Sanctuary Information Center
>
>   Wildlife Warden**
>   Govind Pashu Vihar Sanctuary,
>   [Purola](http://www.euttaranchal.com/tourism/purola.php), [Uttarkashi](http://www.euttaranchal.com/tourism/uttarkashi.php).
>
> and
>
> **Divisional Forest Officer,**
>   Tons Forest Division.
>   Purola, Uttarkashi.

In this [travel company's track itinerary and facts](http://www.thrillophilia.com/tours/har-ki-doon-trek), they do mention that permits are included into what you pay for.
That confirms that you need to have a permit.

From how hard it is to find any information I would suggest looking into doing the track with a company.
[From this page I did not find anything about needing a tour company, but also not about permits.](http://www.euttaranchal.com/tourism/har-ki-doon.php)

As I have never been in the area, an internet search is the best I can do for you.
I did find that Sankri did not bring in many results, searches on Har-Ki-Doon and its alternate spelling Har Ki Dun gave more help. But searching on either separately might be best.

Answer (score 5):

**You do not need a permit for Har Ki Dun trek**. [There is only an entry fee for Govind Pashu national park (that is where Har ki dun trek is)](https://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/har-ki-doon-and-ruinsara-tal-trek.1901/#post-10661). You would need to pay a little extra if you are carrying a still camera or a video camera.

**It is not mandatory to hire a guide**, these travel companies make it look like it is mandatory but it is not. These companies also call the entry ticket a permit to make it sound complicated. Tickets can be purchased at the entrance and there is no paper work involved.

If you want the exact amount for the ticket you can call forest department's Govind Pashu office at 01373223433 (It is a government office). Who ever picks up will be "rude" but that is where you can get first hand and current information. This number is listed on their [official website](http://www.forest.uk.gov.in/files/Contacts_emails/Officewise_Telephone_Directory.pdf).

If you speak to tour operators they will make it sound like it is not possible to go for their trek without hiring their services which is clearly not the case.

Comment: It is a long trek so it is advisable to get a porter that can be hired at the entrance. You do not need to book a porter in advance, there are plenty of them waiting for customers and they double as a guide as they have been on that route many times before.